# Xcode 10 - Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

Existing project working in Xcode 9.3 and suddenly giving error in Openpay Framework while run in Xcode 10 (not beta version).

My swift version is 4.2, if i changed to Swift 4 or Swift 3 then also same error.

**I have tried following things but not worked..**

- pod file update
- clean and build project
- delete derived data and clean-build project
- quit xcode. open again, clean and build.
- sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
- carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries

Comment: it seems like your pods (or at least one of them) is build for Swift 4.1.2, so you need to use that version or update the pods to a version that supports Swift 4.2

Comment: @Scriptable i have already updated the pods but not worked. so i think i want to go to back with swift 4.1.2

Comment: I'm assuming that you added Openpay as a Carthage dependency. Are you sure that `carthage update` properly updated the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `Openpay.framework`in your project (using the link from their readme). The framework is built using Xcode 9.4 - you can check it in `Info.plist` file inside framework (just open it as folder). Here you have several options - ask them to release new version or do it yourself - looks like it is open source library, so you can clone it and build the framework yourself using Xcode 10

Comment: okay i will contact openpay and told them to release new version